# How to Calculate increased amount for each period in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that contains JIRA ticket status summany for each time period, it contains the counts of 'open', 'close' and 'other'. I want to see the increased amount of over tickets period over period.

```
period                              Status  Counts
No. 1 Apr 06 2019 to Apr 12 2019    CLOSE   1026
No. 1 Apr 06 2019 to Apr 12 2019    OPEN    2914
No. 1 Apr 06 2019 to Apr 12 2019    OTHER   264
No. 2 Mar 30 2019 to Apr 05 2019    CLOSE   1307
No. 2 Mar 30 2019 to Apr 05 2019    OPEN    2212
No. 2 Mar 30 2019 to Apr 05 2019    OTHER   256
```

for Period No.1 the count of OPEN status has increased from 2212(period No2) to 
2914, so 702 ticket added for period No1. How do I add and extra colmun that shows.

```
period                              Status  Counts   Added
No. 1 Apr 06 2019 to Apr 12 2019    CLOSE   1026     702 (2914-2212)
No. 1 Apr 06 2019 to Apr 12 2019    OPEN    2914     702 
No. 1 Apr 06 2019 to Apr 12 2019    OTHER   264      702 
No. 2 Mar 30 2019 to Apr 05 2019    CLOSE   1307     (2212 minus  xxx)
No. 2 Mar 30 2019 to Apr 05 2019    OPEN    2212     (2212 minus  xxx)
No. 2 Mar 30 2019 to Apr 05 2019    OTHER   256      (2212 minus  xxx)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can locate the differences in `OPEN`, and then make use of `transform('first')` to fit these values back into the frame.

```
u = df.assign(Added=df.loc[df.Status.eq('OPEN'), 'Counts'].diff(-1))

u.assign(Added=u.groupby('period')['Added'].transform('first'))
```

```
                             period Status  Counts  Added
0  No. 1 Apr 06 2019 to Apr 12 2019  CLOSE    1026  702.0
1  No. 1 Apr 06 2019 to Apr 12 2019   OPEN    2914  702.0
2  No. 1 Apr 06 2019 to Apr 12 2019  OTHER     264  702.0
3  No. 2 Mar 30 2019 to Apr 05 2019  CLOSE    1307    NaN
4  No. 2 Mar 30 2019 to Apr 05 2019   OPEN    2212    NaN
5  No. 2 Mar 30 2019 to Apr 05 2019  OTHER     256    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['added'] = df.loc[df.Status== 'OPEN']['Counts'].diff(periods = -1)
df['added'] = df.groupby(['period'])['added'].bfill()
df['added'] = df.groupby(['period'])['added'].ffill()
```

use diff() function and use backwards and forward fill functions to fill NA.

Answer (score 0):

Start from defining a function to be applied below:

```
def fn(src):
    return src.query("Status == 'OPEN'").Counts
```

Then, by application of this function:

```
df2 = df.groupby('period').apply(fn).diff(-1)\
    .fillna(0, downcast='infer')\
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('Added')
```

you get a DataFrame with `Added` column.

And the last step is to merge both DataFrames:

```
pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='period', right_index=True)
```